# Checkbox cannot be uncheck after a function is called by a button

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I use this code to enable and disable a text input using a checkbox.
it works before i click the "Start Auto Scroll" button, but after that the checkbox not working and I can't change the statusof that checkbox.

```
<td style="border:0px;"><input id ="speed" size="3" maxlength="3"type="text"  disabled="true" name="duration" value="100"></td>
<td> <input id="byMp3" type="checkbox" name="chk" value="byMp3" checked>      Music Tempo</td>

<script>
// this code works before I click on pageScroll()
$('#byMp3').click(function(){
$('#speed').prop('disabled',this.checked);
});

var speed = $('#speed').val();//default
var start = false;  
var page = $("html, body");

function pageScroll() {

if (start == false){
start = true;
$("#scrollBtn").prop('value', 'Stop Auto Scroll');
$endPixel = 800;

if($("#byMp3").is(':checked')){

    var audio = document.getElementById("mp3player");
    duration = parseInt( audio.duration );
    speed = duration;
}
else{
    speed = $('#speed').val();
}

$( "section" ).click(function(e) {
    if (start == false){return false;} 
   page.on("scroll mousedown wheel DOMMouseScroll mousewheel keyup touchmove", function(){
       page.stop();
   });

   page.animate({ scrollTop: $endPixel }, speed*1000);

   return false; 
});
}else
{
start = false;
$("#scrollBtn").prop('value', 'Start Auto Scroll');
page.stop();

return false; 
}
}
</script>
```

What is wrong with this code?